# iOS - Convert a JSON object to an ordered array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, nsdictionary

I have a JSON file with key/value-pairs for a list of countries and their country-codes. I'm reading it with Objective-C and want to present it in a `UIPicker`. 
Problem is, when I store the JSON data into a `NSDictionary`, the original order is lost and the order of the `UIPicker` elements is pretty arbitrary (I know, dictionaries don't have a particular order).

What's the easiest way to preserve to original order? Do I have to create two files, one with the country-codes and one with the country names in the same order and read both into an array? - I really wanna avoid that...

**[Edit]**

As per request, an excerpt of the JSON-Data (stored in a local file)

```
{"af":"Afghanistan",
    "al":"Albania",
    "dz":"Algeria",
    "as":"American Samoa",
    "ad":"Andorra",
    "ao":"Angola",
    "ai":"Anguilla",
    "aq":"Antarctica",
    "ag":"Antigua and Barbuda",
    "ar":"Argentina",
    "am":"Armenia",
    "aw":"Aruba",
    "ac":"Ascension Island (Atlantic ocean)",
    "au":"Australia",
    "at":"Austria",
    "az":"Azerbaijan",
    "bs":"Bahamas",
    "bh":"Bahrain",
    "bd":"Bangladesh",
    "bb":"Barbados",
    "by":"Belarus",
    "be":"Belgium",
    "bz":"Belize",
    "bj":"Benin",
    "bm":"Bermuda",
    "bt":"Bhutan",
    "bo":"Bolivia",
    "ba":"Bosnia",
    "bw":"Botswana",
    "bv":"Bouvet Island (Atlantic ocean)",
    "br":"Brazil",
    ... }
```

**[Edit 2]**

I'm using this code to read the JSON data and convert it to a `NSDictionary`:

```
NSURL *jsonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"countries" withExtension:@"json"];
NSString *stringPath = [jsonPath absoluteString];

NSData *countriesJSON = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringPath]];

NSDictionary *parsedJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:countriesJSON options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: Can you please share the json format in which you receive the data

Comment: What's your code for converting the JSON array to NSDictionary

Comment: `What's the easiest way to preserve to original order?` Dictionary is not a ordered container. There is no such thing as original order. If you want it ordered, sort it first.

Comment: @Desdenova: As you can see, the original JSON data IS ordered. It just gets lost when I convert the JSON data into an NSDictionary. Hence my question ;)

Comment: No, it's not. Next time you print it you may or may not get the same order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your JSON data to

```
[
{"af":"Afghanistan"},
{"al":"Albania"},
{"dz":"Algeria"},
{"as":"American Samoa"},
{"ad":"Andorra"},
{"ao":"Angola"},
{"ai":"Anguilla"},
...
]
```

Then use the code like:

```
NSURL *jsonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample" withExtension:@"json"];
NSData *countriesJSON = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonPath];
NSMutableArray *countryArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: countriesJSON options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

The JSON is converted to a ordered array called `countryArray`. the elements of the `countryArray` is a `NSDictionary` instance.

Comment: Thanks Cokile. Kinda like Skensell's suggestions, just the other way around... ;) I'll give both of your suggestions a shot. Just too bad that there's no possibility to do it without altering the original file...

Comment: @Swissdude OK. But your code has a problem. There is no need to create `stringPath`. Just use `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonPath]`

Comment: Thanks again, CokileCeoi. I used your version. Was the easiest way... - and thanks for the hint with the stringPath - I have no idea where this came from (copy paste from some webpage, I guess...)

Answer (score 1):

If order is important and you have access to the JSON file, then you could change your JSON to be an array like so:

```
[
    ["Afghanistan", "AF"],
    ["Bangladesh", "BD"]
]
```

Then when you deserialize it, order will be preserved because the deserialized object will be an array of arrays.

If you don't have access to your JSON file then you could create this array of arrays from your Dictionary in code.

**Edit**

If you want both quick lookups and an ordering then it's tough to avoid using 2 data structures. With the JSON file you've submitted, it seems you want an array:

```
NSArray *countriesSorted = [parsedJson.allValues sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

However, it would be better for you to switch the order of values in your json file to be country-name:country-code.  Then you could do

```
NSArray *countryCodesSorted = [parsedJson.allKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSString *firstCountryName = parsedJson[countryCodesSorted[0]];
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I do have access to the JSON-file. If there's no other solution coming up, I'll give your suggestion a try...

Answer (score 1):

The issue of *order* and dictionaries often occurs when the dictionary needs to be displayed in a tableview.  The established solution to this is to keep a separate array of dictionary keys alongside the dictionary.  You can re-order the array as you (or the user) likes and do a two-stage fetch of dictionary entries via the array.  This allows you to keep your original JSON format and internal storage properties/instance variables.

YourClass.m:

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property NSMutableArray *dictOrder;
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)getData
{
    self.dict = // Get dictonary from JSON
    self.dictOrder = [[self.dict allKeys] mutableCopy];
    [self.dictOrder sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}


// UITableViewDataSource example
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Normal cell re-use stuff
    NSString *key = self.dictOrder[indexPath.row];
    NSString *country = self.dict[key];
    // Populate cell
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks Droppy - interesting approach. I went with CokileCeoi's solution - involved the least work ;)